# Missing credentials for "PLAIN" - nodemailer

Tags: javascript, smtp, nodemailer

I'm trying to send an e-mail from my backend, but for some reason it won't accept this:

```js
async function sendEmail(text, subject) {
    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: "smtp.world4you.com",
        port: 587,
        secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
        auth: {
            user: process.env.MAIL_USER, // generated ethereal user
            pass: process.env.MAIL_PASSWORD, // generated ethereal password
        },
    });

    let info = await transporter.sendMail({
        from: process.env.MAIL_USER, // sender address
        to: process.env.MAIL_RECEIVER, // list of receivers
        subject: subject, // Subject line
        text: text, // plain text body
    });

    console.log(info)
}
```

(I'm also happy with any alternatives)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you use **dotenv** correctly. I traced it back and the problem was that my password and email were undefined, because I forgot to require dotenv like this:

```js
require('dotenv').config()
```